# Text in between <b></b> programmatic bold string in between and nilling<b></b> UILabel swift

Tags: swift, uilabel, swift2

I have core data objects that contain strings that have  as markers to make that part of code bold. Is there anyway way of checking for these things in swift making the in between text bold and making the  code invisible to the user? I am still new to coding and new to swift language. How would you go about doing this? This is for iOS.

Comment: NSAttributedString and read string as HTML text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = "<b>Hello, playground</b>"
do{
    let atrString = try NSAttributedString(data:str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
}catch{
    print("Could not convert!")
}
```

You will first need to convert the text to NSData using `dataUsingEncoding()` than try to make a NSAttributedString with an HTML Text document type

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 version of [milo526 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33103298/3736373).

```
do{
    let atrString = try NSAttributedString(data: str.data(using: .utf8) ?? .init(), options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
}catch{
    print("Could not convert!")
}
```